# Getting Shopify Plan names and limitations through API

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

Is there a way to find out through the API what are the current available plans and their corresponding limitations? The current API has a `GET /admin/shop.json` point that returns a `plan_name` field, but there is no enumeration of what these plans are.

Comment: No but this may help: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/enumeration-of-plan_name-from-get-admin-shop-json-352847

Answer (score 0):

Not possible through the API. The best you can really do is to build a static list with this data from http://www.shopify.com/pricing since it doesn't change often.